# Is there a compiler define for Unity that is always enabled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does Unity define any scripting symbols for all platforms, all of the time?

I am looking for something like this:

```ml
#if UNITY3D
// We are being compiled by Unity 3D
#endif
```

There is a list [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), but it doesn't mention what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're looking for exactly. For starters **Unity3D** is the same as **Unity2D**. The main difference is what objects you use in your scene and how your camera is set up. However, if you want to create a *custom scripting symbol* to specify custom conditions on a specific build (or even while in the `Editor`), the link you provided also has the information on how to do that. Otherwise, the link you provided already has all the info on how to target certain platforms or conditions.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Assembly Definitions?  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - something I never understood either but there are only the version specific defines.

=> Simply choose the earliest version (pick any older one) you want to support and use e.g.

```
#if UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER
// any Unity version since 5.3.1
#endif
```

a bit uncanny but it seems to be the best option in this way.